# How to swap components (with ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush)?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-changedetection

[image: Application structure]
[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hhkbps?embed=1&file=src/app/component-a/component-a.component.ts)

This is what I have understood -

1. On clicking the swap button (present in *sub-component-a.ts*), an event is trigged.
2. This event is heard in *app.component.ts* which performs simple swapping operation on first two car objects.
3. The *component-a.ts* view is updated (without its OnChanges()) being called).
4. The *sub-component-a.ts* (which has @Input() position reference changed) is not updated.

How to swap two *component-a*, with their corresponding child components, *sub-component-a* also getting updated?